# Extract all partial matches: AGGREGRATE FORMULA TO replicate in GOOGLE SHEET

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language, partial-matches

I need help on replicating below formula into Google sheet. Since google sheet does not support Aggregate, I am having difficulties replicating it into google sheet.

I need a formula which will list out all partial match item based on specific text from data.

Help is much appreciated.

Below is the formula I am using in excel:

```
=IFERROR(IF(F5>$D$9,"",INDEX($B$5:$B$16,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$5:$B$16)-ROW($B$5)+1)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$5,$B$5:$B$16)),F5)))," ")
```

and below is sample data and result outcome:

[image]

Comment: Welcome. How do you get the `Count: 12`? What do you count? Also. What do the numbers represent next to `Result`?

Answer (score 2):

use in F2:

```
=QUERY(A2:A; "select A where A contains '"&C2&"' limit "&C6; 0)
```

or case insensitive:

```
=QUERY(A2:A; "select A where lower(A) contains '"&LOWER(C2)&"' limit "&C6; 0)
```